# Fix bug can not read data from COM ( PCI express - serial) in window form application (C#)

Tags: c#, serial-port, port, uart, pci

I have a small window form application (C#): Read data from barcode by COM UART RS232 and display to textbox

- If I connect barcode with COM extension ( PCI express serial), after scan barcode => data only have /0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0
- If I connect barcode with default COM ( communication COM) of computer => It's OK.
  How can I fix that with extension COM ?
  the below is my Code :

```
 string path = ".\\Setting\\Config.ini";
            IniFile inisys = new IniFile(path);

            string PortName = inisys.GetString("FORMULA", "BarcodeCOM", "COM5");
            int BaudRate = inisys.GetInt32("FORMULA", "baudrate", 9600);
           
            port = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Open();
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                // set the 'invoke' delegate and attach the 'receive-data' function
                // to the serial port 'receive' event.
                accessControlFromCentralThread = displayTextReadIn;
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            }
```

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs rcvdData)
        {

            while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                lineReadIn += port.ReadExisting();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            // display what we've acquired.
            displayTextReadIn(lineReadIn);
```

}

```
private void displayTextReadIn(string ToBeDisplayed)
        {
            if (Txt_itemNo.InvokeRequired)
                Txt_itemNo.Invoke(accessControlFromCentralThread, ToBeDisplayed);
            else
                Txt_itemNo.Text = ToBeDisplayed;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "COM extension (PCI express serial)"? A PCI card with a serial port as opposed to a serial port directly on the motherboard?

Comment: @Codo, can you explain more about you mind ?. Please see hardware in my computer. I input more 1 COM by PCI express serial. If i Connect barcode via COM of mother board and run application => it's OK. but when I connect barcode via extension COM and run application => It is not OK. and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I still do not understand what hardware you are using. Most likely, your C# code is okay. The problem is more likely with the cable, the driver or the serial port configuration. Use a serial terminal program like PuTTY, HyperTerminal or TeraTerm test different settings, check drivers etc. until you get the expected data. Then return to your C# code.

Comment: Did you install the driver for your PCI Express card provided by the manufacturer?

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/

Comment: @Codo, I have others software use same hardware, same function and that work well. ( I don't know code of that software). so , I think hardware is OK. I already install driver for hardware. I don't know what is difference between PCI express serial and communication port on the mother board ?.

Comment: @user9938 thank for your comment. I already install diver for PCI express card. but that still not OK.

Comment: You mentioned that the port on the mother board works. Did you try changing the motherboard port to COM5 (or COM 6) and checking if it still works?